# how display 839,99.00 value instead of 83,999.00 in using decimal format in java

Tags: format, decimal

My current format  for decimal is  "###,##0.00"  for that value is displayed is 839,99.00

I want display that value as 839,99.00

Answer (score 0):

That seems like the US locale;

```
NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(yourNumber);
```

alternatively this `#,###.00` should work.